# Matlab: Write text to PDF

Tags: matlab, pdf, export

I'd like to create a PDF out of my matlab m-function. The PDF should contain some text information which I want to style a bit and one image (which is previously generated as figure). Is there any way? The only thing I found is `publish` to publish source-code. The only alternative I could think off was to programm the texts into the figure window and than export the whole figure to pdf. Perhaps there's a better way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: I have written code that writes a LaTeX file and then calls pdflatex. This works quite well. Note that if your problem is sufficiently simple, then you can use `publish` and add the option to not show the source code.

Comment: so one can call pdflatex from matlab? I need a solution where no external tools and no external calla are needed thus I call my function and get a PDF. How to get there, is not that important, as long as theres no need to code for years :D

Comment: pdflatex can be called from within Matlab (see the answer by @dantswain), but it is an external program. If you cannot rely on third-party programs, your only option seems to be `publish` (which also allows some LaTeX commands to style text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend generating your figure with Matlab, outputting it to eps, then converting the figure to pdf using [epstopdf](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/epstopdf).  Then embed your figure in a latex document and generate a pdf with pdflatex.

I know this sounds like an incredibly roundabout way of doing it, but

1. This is the way I've come to do it after years of experience and it always gives me the best results
2. Every one of my colleagues does it this way for the same reason
3. The results will be completely reproducible
4. You're using Matlab to do what it's good at (making scientific figures) and latex to do what it's good at (formatting documents)

The Matlab code to make the eps of the figure would be like this (supposing your figure is figure 1):

```
print -depsc2 -f1 -loose my_fig.eps
```

You could pretty easily write a latex template that uses `my_fig.pdf` and then run everything from your Matlab using bangouts:

```
!epstopdf my_fig
!pdflatex mydoc.tex
```

Comment: I create pdf figures using `export_fig`, which gives very nice results.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, you can connect to Word using 'actxserver', insert and style any text you like into a blank document, copy and paste MATLAB figures into the document, and then save it to PDF. You can do all of that from within MATLAB. The first time you do this it's a pain, as you need to learn quite a bit about the Word Object Model; but once you've done it a couple of times it's very simple and quick, and you can achieve very professional results. You can combine this with using the 'export_fig' that others have mentioned.